# Read value from application.ini in ZEND framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

This must be a simple thing but I still couldn't read resourse values from application.ini in Zend framework 2 after going through several threads.
I have a module and inside the module I have a controller.I want to get the values in resourse file in this controller.

```
namespace myModule\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class myController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function handlerAction() {
        // I want to read application.ini values here 
    }
}
```

**`application.ini`** is as below:

```
[lables]
dom.title = Lable 01
```

I tried to get this values with,

```
$config = $this->getApplication()->getOption('dom');
```

But still no luck. Help me to figure this out.

Thankx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php native function [**`parse_ini_file()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php). Because you have sections (I suppose it is `labels` instead of `lables`), use it this way:

```
$iniArray = parse_ini_file($pathToFile . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'application.ini', true);
$domTitle = $iniArray['labels']['dom.title'] ;
```